# How to word request to undertake a project as a research intern rather than as a thesis, without offending potential supervisor?

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, thesis, supervision, internship

Competitive STEM program and for our final thesis  many of the potential advisors have multiple applicants per project.

After being rejected for one project (initially seemed to be the top choice but someone with two strong conference papers applied), I decided to reach out to multiple advisors - figured it’s best to protect my downside.

I got my first choice but prior to this I had agreed to do a literature review for another project that I roughly drew up with a  professor. I really want to work on this project but not as my msc thesis as there’s more uncertainty (at least from where I stand) as to whether or not it will result in a paper and requires more setup time (e.g. the literature and defining the problem). I would like to ask to do this 2nd project as a research intern after I graduate as it’s an interesting problem and the professor seems great but I don’t want to somehow offend him when I state that I have decided to do a different project for my thesis. I’ve noticed quite a few senior academics can be easily offended - not saying he is but I’d like to minimize this possibility.

I am autistic and sometimes accidentally come across as rude. How should I phrase my email?

Comment: I am confused by your post. Can you clarify?